# PHPExcel - find sheet state

Tags: phpexcel

How to get sheet state in PHP Excel? "getVisible" only works for rows or columns, but not sheet. I could not find any similar method as "setSheetState", either. I need to find out if the first sheet of a workbook is hidden or visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. There is a method getSheetState(). Just guessed it and it worked. It should have been included in the documentation, though.

Comment: The documentation does include the API docs, which give details of all methods available